# bar plot with 3 y axis values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), b = c(10, 20 , 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80), c = c(4, 5, 6, 34, 5, 22, 12, 45), d = c(1,2,3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1))

df <- df %>%
    mutate(Type = case_when(d <= 1 ~ 'A',
                            d <= 2 ~ 'B',
                            d > 2 ~ 'C'))
df


# A tibble: 8 x 5
      a     b     c     d Type 
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1    10     4     1 A    
2     2    20     5     2 B    
3     3    30     6     3 C    
4     4    40    34     3 C    
5     5    50     5     3 C    
6     6    60    22     2 B    
7     7    70    12     1 A    
8     8    80    45     1 A
```

I want to plot a bar plot where I should have the 3 values (columns a,b,c) by each type.

My problem is how to show three different y axis values.

I want something like that:

[image]

which will have A, B and C cases side by side (in the image it's only A).

The problem is how to show the 3 values.

Comment: (To me) the desired output is not clear: could you add a mock up of it?

Comment: great: last question, you have several type == "A" (row 1, 7, 8). Each one is a plot, or you have only one plot for A (with value a 1+7+8, b 10 + 70 +80...)?

Comment: @s_t: I have only one plot for A (maybe the sum or mean of values).Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
library(reshape2)
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
group_by(Type) %>%                        # group by
summarise_all(sum) %>%                    # function that summarise the numbers: you can use mean or whatever you want
reshape2::melt() %>%                      # from wide to long format
  ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value)) +  # now plot it!
  geom_bar(stat ='identity') +
  facet_wrap(vars(Type))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a cool package named `cowplot`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

d <- df %>% 
  select(-d) %>%             # remove variable "d"
  group_by(Type) %>%         # group by Type
  summarise_all(sum) %>%     # sum all columns values for each Type
  gather("x","y",-Type) %>%  # Transform the data in x(variable) and y(count) for each Type 
  nest(-Type) %>%            # Nest by Type
  rowwise() %>%              # Apply transformations by line
  mutate(plot = list(ggplot(data,aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
                     geom_bar(stat ='identity') + 
                     theme_bw() + 
                     labs(title = Type) +
                     ylab("Value") + 
                     xlab("") + 
                     theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5))))

# plot the charts side by side using cowplot
plot_grid(plotlist = d$plot,nrow = 1)
```

[image]